# Parse.com retrieve data PHP

Tags: php, parse-platform

Animation
[image]

User
[image]

I'm trying to retrieve the user id for the creator of the animation object as below.  When I echo $userID I see an array - looks like it's a pointer to the user object.  How do I get the username from the user object?

Or would I be better saving the user id as a string in the animation class when I create the animation object?

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Animation");
$query->descending("createdAt");
$query->limit(2);
$results = $query->find();


for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) { 
  $object = $results[$i];
  $file = $object->get("gifFile");
  $url = $file->getURL();
  $userID = $object->get("createdBy");
```

Here's a dump of $userID

> Parse\ParseUser Object ( [_sessionToken:protected] =>
>   [serverData:protected] => Array ( ) [operationSet:protected] => Array
>   ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( )
>   [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( )
>   [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => _User
>   [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => xmoc179ICy
>   [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] =>
>   [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] =>
>   [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => ) Parse\ParseUser Object
>   ( [_sessionToken:protected] => [serverData:protected] => Array ( )
>   [operationSet:protected] => Array ( )
>   [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( )
>   [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( )
>   [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => _User
>   [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => xmoc179ICy
>   [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] =>
>   [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] =>
>   [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => )

Update - working code :

```
    $query = new ParseQuery("Animation");
    $query->includeKey("createdBy");
    $query->descending("createdAt");
    $query->limit(2);
    $results = $query->find();


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) { 

      $object = $results[$i];
      $user = $object->get("createdBy");
      $username = $user->get("username");


      echo($username);
}
```

Comment: What does the `$userID` look like if you run `print_r` or `var_dump`? Maybe you just need to fetch what's inside like. `$userID['name']` or `$userID->name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default queries won't fetch nested/related objects, so you basically get a pointer.

Try looking at [`ParseQuery::includeKey()`](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseQuery.php#L829).